# Problem with string manipulation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, datetime

I have been working on a python Data Visualization project of WhatsApp Chat. I have a string like this.

```
line = '[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM] Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies to night'
```

And I want to break it down to exactly like this.

```
['[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM]', 'Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies to night']
```

I have tried doing with `split()` function, but I can't seem to get this exact same thing. Also first time field will vary so length of that field might not be the same every time.

I would appriciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: maybe `[line[:line.index(']')+1], line[line.index(']')+2:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find) the first occurrence of `]` and use that for [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation):

```
[line[:line.find(']')+1],line[line.find(']')+2:]]
```

BTW: It should be faster to use a helper variable for the find result, which might be better for you when you are doing DataViz:

```
f=line.find(']')
[line[:f+1],line[f+2:]]
```

Results from timeit:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("line = '[14/11/18, 11:47:26 PM] Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies [to] night'; [line[:line.find(']')+1],line[line.find(']')+2:]]")
0.33965302700016764
>>> timeit.timeit("line = '[14/11/18, 11:47:26 PM] Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies [to] night'; f=line.find(']'); [line[:f+1],line[f+2:]]")
0.21619235799971648
```

Comment: Yes, This is perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
r = line.split(']', 1)
r[0] += ']'
```

Comment: Also if message contains any ']' then also this would might fail.

Comment: @ghostshelltaken it will split on first occurence

Answer (score 1):

```py
line = '[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM] Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies to night'
reslist =line.split(']',1)
reslist[0] += "]" # needed because split removes delimiter
reslist[1] = reslist[1].lstrip()
print(reslist) # ['[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM]', 'Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies to night']
```

Comment: This fails if the message contains any ']'.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.split(r'(?<=\])\s', line, 1)
['[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM]', 'Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies to night']
```

It will split at whitespace if there is a bracket in front of it and only split once.

- `\s` matches any whitespace
- `(?<=\])` is a look behind to look for `]` (denoted as `\]`)

Comment: Thanks this works and I would appreciate if you would have shown how this works since I am not familier with `import re`.

Comment: @ghostshelltaken i gave a short explanation and shortend the regex. maybe it helps a bit

Comment: This helps, Thanks. I will aslo look into `re`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess we take for granted that the format of the date is a constant thus we have a max length of it of 22.

```
line = '[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM] Chaitanya: Yeah, Lets go to the movies to night'
loc = line.find(']',0,22)   # find its location => 21 

our_result = [
    line[0:loc+1], line[loc+2:]
]
```

Comment: The format of the date is not constant: `[14/11/18, 2:47:26 PM]` or  `[14/11/18, 10:47:26 PM]`

Comment: when I said constant I meant length will not be larger than 22

Comment: Yes, but your code is not working when the time is bigger than 9: find will return -1, just try it. You must either set the end parameter of `find` to 23 or drop the start and end parameter completely, because find will return the first occurrence.

Comment: just add a simple if to check for it:

if loc == -1:
    loc = line.find(']',0,23)